# Discord.py how to get message author from the message id

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, payload

I'm new to programming discord bots. I'm currently using `on_raw_reaction_add(payload)` and `on_raw_reaction_remove(payload)` in order to keep track of how many times a certain reaction is used. Is there a way that I can get the message author from the payload or get the message author from `payload.message_id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above answer is partially correct, you need `TextChannel.fetch_message()` not `Client.fetch_message()`

```py
msg = await bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id).fetch_message(payload.message_id)
author = msg.author
```

Comment: This just gives me an error: `AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'author'`

Answer (score 1):

I misread the docs. Thanks to @Poojan for pointing that out.
To fix the error you're getting from their answer, you need to await the command. I assume this is because fetch_message calls some sort of http request instead of copying information from memory. This means there is a delay from the request to the information being received, and you need to use the keyword "await" to wait for it.

```
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    msg = await bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id).fetch_message(payload.message_id)
    author = msg.author
    print(author.display_name)
```

Tested and it outputs my display name. Author is a user object.

Comment: This is just giving me an error: `AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'fetch_message'`